# Nested foreach loop on a json array, mapping index to value

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I currently have a decoded JSON array

```
+"productINF": {#1260 ▼
  +"product": {#1011 ▼
    +"productCode": "123"
    +"productType": {#999 ▼
      +"count": 3.0
      +"desc": "Block"
    }
  }
}
+"price": {#1267 ▼
  +"02": "470.00"
}
```

And I'm performing multiple foreach loops to get info from each level that I need.
The problem is that I have two things on the same level, each their own array: productINF and price.

The first has info on the product and the second has price info. The issue is that in the current JSON array the price is `"02" : "470.00"` but sometimes there may be multiple prices like so:

```
+"01": "40.00",
+"05": "240.00"
```

I don't ever know what the key is going to be but I just want to make sure that foreach item, I call the 2nd value as the price. Here's how I'm looping now, but I don't know how to set the price to a value correctly:

```
 foreach($category->skus as $sku){
      foreach($sku->productINF as $info){
          $productCode = $info->productCode;

          foreach($info->productType as $type){
              $count = $type->count;
              $desc = $type->desc;
          }
      }
      foreach ($sku->price as $price) {
         //Not sure how to access price here
      }
  }
```

Comment: When there are multiple prices you want all of them in an array or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreach will treat objects the same as arrays.

This should do...

```
foreach ($sku->price as $price) {
    foreach ($price as $id => $amount) {
        echo $id , ' ' , $amount , "\n";
    }
}
```